# search with inadmissible heuristics

Tags: search-algorithms, heuristics

I was told that search algorithm such as IDA* or Beam Search with any inadmissible heuristic is not guaranteed to find a solution. Can someone explain why that is the case? I was thinking sure the solution may not be optimal as the agent is too pessimistic to try out a potentially optimal path, but as least it will try some path and which could be a sub-optimal solution (i.e. the search algorithm is at least sound and complete)?

Answer (score 2):

Beam Search can fail to find any solution even with an admissible heuristic. (Suppose the beam has width $k=1$ and the root node has two children, $a$ and $b$, with $b$ being a solution and there is no solution reachable from $a$. Let $C(v)$ be the true cost of an optimal solution via vertex $v$ and $\infty$ if no solution via $v$ exists, and $H(\cdot)$ be an admissible heuristic for $C(\cdot)$. Then it could be that $C(a) = \infty$ but $H(a) < H(b) \le C(b) < \infty$, in which case the only solution, $b$, is discarded immediately.)

IDA* will find a (possibly suboptimal) solution if an inadmissible heuristic is used.

Comment: I just read a textbook which says that IDA* will not keep all the reached states in memory. Maybe that's why it can fail to find the solution when the heuristic is inadmissible, as when it choose to ignore a node it will never expand it again?

Comment: IDA* comprises a series of DFS passes that each start from scratch and proceed until a pass-specific cost cutoff. At some point during each pass, _every_ node below that pass's cost cutoff will be generated -- but none of them are saved in memory. The cost cutoff increases with each pass, so each pass will generate all nodes generated in all preceding passes (plus a few more).